# Cant Get Bootstrap Table To Resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get a bootstrap table to resize so that the maximum content height is 200px and anything greater will scroll.

I have the css for the table set to:

```
table.jSpeeds tr:hover, table.jSpeeds tr td:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

table.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}
table.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

& HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped jSpeeds table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr><th>Time</th><th>Speed</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>TestRow</td><td>TestVal</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However the table is still the height and width of the page. I was wondering if anyone could help.

[Please see the JSBin example here](http://jsbin.com/libuyukebi/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use bootstrap's [responsive-table](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/#responsive-tables). Wrap your `<table>` with this.

```
<div class="table-responsive fix-table-height">
    // your table here
</div>
```

Then add the class `fix-table-height` on the wrapper so you could define the height of the wrapper. In your case you want `200px;`. So you can do this :

```
.fix-table-height{
    max-height:200px;
}
```

This is the output [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/bek84Lku/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your table's body and rows display to block. Do something like this:

```
table.jSpeeds tr:hover, table.jSpeeds tr td:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

table.table-fixed thead {
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.table-fixed tbody,
table.table-fixed tr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-fixed th,
table.table-fixed td {
  width: 300px;
}
```

**EDIT**

Since I was challenged to give a robust solution, here is comes:

```
table.jSpeeds tr:hover, table.jSpeeds tr td:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}

table.table-fixed thead {
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

table.table-fixed tbody,
table.table-fixed tr {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

table.table-fixed th,
table.table-fixed td {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[Gist Link](http://output.jsbin.com/beregec)

Comment: you have to explicitly add a with for the td. This is not a robust solution

Answer (score 0):

just adjust your css to this:

```
tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 230px;
}

tbody tr {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: the tbody as child of the table will get automatically the width property given to the table. in this case 100% ;-).

Comment: of course! did you put the same properties for the thead too? and the styles for the "tr" in the thead too? it's self-evident, seems like you forgot them